# exact path of the header file that need to be included for accessing user-space memory access functions like- access_ok(), get_from_user().?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

i searched for user memory access functions in linux-headers-3.2.0-49. it is defined in uaccess.h header file But there are too many uaccess.h files.
Below is what i get by doing "find . -name uaccess.h" inside linux-headers-3.2.0-49 directory.

```
./include/linux/uaccess.h
./include/asm-generic/uaccess.h
./arch/frv/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/cris/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/cris/include/arch-v32/arch/uaccess.h
./arch/cris/include/arch-v10/arch/uaccess.h
./arch/um/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/blackfin/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/openrisc/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/parisc/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/sparc/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/mips/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/avr32/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/alpha/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/sh/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/m68k/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/arm/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/m32r/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/hexagon/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/tile/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/microblaze/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/mn10300/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/unicore32/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/h8300/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/s390/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/ia64/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/xtensa/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/powerpc/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/score/include/asm/uaccess.h
./arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h
```

Can anyone tell me which path to include for accessing access_ok(), get_from_user() etc functions...?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following [link](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/ldd-examples/scull/main.c). This has some examples for using `access_ok()`.

Comment: i have first included uaccess.h as u have said that is #include<linux/uaccess.h>        But on make its showing that      error : linux/uaccess.h: No such file or directory

Comment: I have updated with an example, what errors are you getting. Its always best to provide more details on the errors & what you are trying to achieve. note, you should be using `asm/uaccess.h` and not `linux/uaccess.h`, I have updated the previous posting.

Comment: now #include<linux/uaccess.h> is being added(when i set two variables C_INCLUDE_PATH and CXX_INCLUDE_PATH to /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-65-generic/include:/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-65/arch/x86/include ). But now on MAKE,

Comment: But now on MAKE, i m getting some new errors:    like:      error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type,error: #error BITS_PER_LONG not 32 or 64 etc